# Gibt es im Deutschen viele Wörter, die durch Transposition eines einzigen Buchstabens eine neue Bedeutung bekommen?

Tags: spelling, curiosity

Gibt es im Deutschen viele Wörter, die durch Transposition eines einzigen Buchstabens eine neue Bedeutung bekommen?

Beispielsweise

> beliebt

und

> beleibt.

Comment: Definiere "viele". Sieben? Siebenhundert? Siebenhundert mehr als im Russischen?

Comment: Sorry, aber das ist eindeutig außerhalb des "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." aus den [faq](http://german.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I found this question interesting, despite its theoretical nature. It is certainly answerable.

Comment: I should add that it should be rewritten as "wieveiele Wörter?"

Comment: Diese Frage hat einen praktischen Bezug - man könnte Rechtschreibhilfen programmieren, die solche einfachen Transpositionen korrigieren. Wenn man die Frage in "Wieviele Wörter" ändert, ist sie definitiv auch beantwortbar. "Viele" dient hier nur der groben Abschätzung. Vielleicht ist die Frage schwierig zu beantworten, aber trotzdem meiner Meinung nach passend für German.SE

Comment: Im Wörterbuch auf http://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/files/ gibt es 2234 solche Worte (bei 1239864 Worten insgesamt). Keine Ahnung, ob das jetzt "viel" ist aber die Frage, die ich mir stelle ist: Was bringt uns diese Erkenntnis?!

Comment: Es hat mich in dem Augenblick einfach interessiert ;)

Comment: Das wäre doch die perfekte Antwort: Ja, 2234.

Comment: @sl0815: Mich würde interessieren wie Du die Anzahl ermittelt hast. Ich habe mein Wörterbuch erst nach Wortlängen geordnet, weil 2 Kandidaten auf Transpositionsgleichheit notwendig gleich lang sein müssen. Dann habe ich die Buchstaben der Worte alphabetisch sortiert und die so entstandenen Wörter alphabetisch sorttiert. Damit stehen Permutationen Tp-gleicher Wörter nebeneinander (oder in einer Kette, wenn es mehr als 2 sind) - aber es sind auch noch solche dabei, bei denen mehr als ein Buchstabe bewegt werden müsste (Bundesinnenminister - Bundesministerinnen).

Comment: Zu klären wäre noch, ob Groß-/Kleinschreibung berücksichtigt werden muss (Chi-ich) und ob Eigennamen erlaubt sind (Zeus-Zuse). :)  Ich stimme übrigens dafür die Frage wieder zu öffnen.

Comment: Does beliebt to bliebet count (just moving the first e)? I reckon not, but not sure