# Welches deutsche Wort hat die meisten Konsonanten in Folge?

Tags: vocabulary, curiosity

Der Titel sagt fast alles. Ich suche nicht nur echte "im Duden stehenden" Wörter, sondern auch leicht konstruierte Wörter, die aber immer noch einen Sinn haben, würden mich interessieren.

Mit Google finde ich keine eindeutige Antwort zu dieser Frage, deshalb stelle ich sie hier.

Comment: Wie kann eine Antwort mehrdeutig sein? Die Antwort mit den meisten Konsonanten ist die richtige.

Comment: Wenn man so ein Beispiel konstruieren will, dann wird es wohl auf ein `sch`am Wortende und dann ein `Th`am Anfang des nächsten Wortes hinauslaufen.

Comment: @Tim: Eine Antwort ist mehrdeutig, wenn mehrere Wörter mit der Maximalzahl an Konsonanten in Folge existieren.

Comment: angeblich kennt mein lehrer ein wort mit 24 in folge es gibt da eine seite genau kenne ic hsie nicht geschweige wie sie heisst aber dort befassen sich die leute nur damit (als hobby)

Comment: Sind in der Frage wirklich Konsonanten oder **Konsonantenbuchstaben** gemeint? Zählt bspw. _z_ als 2 Konsonanten, _ng_ als 1 Konsonant?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### 8

Ich biete 8, und die Antwort ist eindeutig - nur eine Lösung*:

```
sed 's|/.*||' /var/cache/postgresql/dicts/de_de.dict | egrep  "[^aeiouAEIOUÄÖÜäöüyY]{8,}"
```

#### <strike>Rechtsschreibung</strike>

Andere Wörterbücher habe ich <strike>noch nicht</strike> jetzt getestet: /usr/share/dict/ogerman

```
Angstschweiß
Angstschwelle
Gerichtsschreiber
Geschichtsschreiber
Geschichtsschreibung
Glückwunschschreiben
```

Interressant, dass ogerman keine Rechtschreibung kennt. Vielleicht, weil man die `Rechtschreibung` schreibt, und nicht `Recht`**s**`schreibung` - das ist wohl eher das Gegenteil von dem, was Linkshänder mit einem Stift machen? :)

Zum Teil ist das von Hauser aber schon gefunden worden.

Comment: +1 Kreativ und nerdig!

Comment: Wie wärs noch mit `/usr/share/ngerman`

Comment: `ngerman` liefert auch nichts neues in dieser Hinsicht.

Comment: Applaus dafür, nicht Perl verwendet zu haben... ;-)

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/458/gibt-es-im-deutschen-viele-worter-die-durch-transposition-eines-einzigen-buchsta you seem to be talented :) Maybe a way to solve that question with clever & smart use of regular expressions and a small script too?! Should also be reopened, dont see whats different to this one...

Comment: sl0815 hat die Frage ja beantwortet, wenn auch ohne die Methode offenzulegen, oder die 2k Wörter aufzulisten.

Comment: Meine Datei hat ca. 320 000 Worte. Wenn man jedes mit jedem auf Übereinstimmungen abgleicht kommt man auf 320 000², oder rd. 100 Mrd. Vergleiche. Allerdings kann man für ein Wort wie `man` mit 3 Buchstaben nach 2 Transpositionen suchen: `amn` Und `mna`, für Wörter mit x Zeichen x-1 Transpositionen. Die mittlere Wortlänge ist 13 Zeichen (im Ernst - alleine über 50 Wörter, die mit `Agrar~` beginnen) so dass man mit einer Brute-force-Methode auf eine Billion Vergleiche käme. Wie weit man dabei mit regulären Ausdrücken kommt transzendiert die Möglichkeiten des Kommentars, und ist **hier** offtopic

Answer (score 8):

Das zusammengesetzte Wort

> Herbstschnee

hat auch acht aufeinanderfolgende Konsonanten.

Ein etwas exotisches, aber gültiges Wort mit **neun Konsonanten** in Folge ist

> Borschtschspezialität

[Borschtsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borschtsch) ist eine Suppe, die ihren Ursprung in Osteuropa hat.

Beide Wörter habe ich [hier](http://www.matheboard.de/archive/16348/thread.html) gefunden.

Comment: Ich weiß aber nicht, ob ich der Borschtschschreibung folgen kann. Entführe das Wort aber für den Fall das, um 12 zu bieten.

Comment: @splattne Hat Borschtschspezialität nicht 10 Konsonanten in Folge?

Comment: @user unknown `für den Fall, dass ...` und wahrscheinlich ist gemeint: `Ich entführe das Wort aber, um 12 Konsonanten anzubieten.`

Answer (score 7):

Direkt vom Nützer »Christopher« im [»Wer-weiss-was-forum«](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article4519810.html) angegeben:

> Wenn du eine Mischung aus einem Fremdwort und einem Austriazismus akzeptierst, wird dir **Borschtschgschnas**‹ mit unschlagbaren 13 geschriebenen und sieben gesprochenen Konsonanten gefallen. ›*Borschtsch*‹ ist eine russische Rote-Bete-Suppe, ›*Gschnas*‹ ein österreichischer Begriff für einen Maskenball.

Comment: Klingt für mich wie Schwanzhund.

Comment: Ich glaube, das Wort »Borschtschgschnas« hat seinen Anfang im Internet in meiner Datenbank des nutzlosen Wissen genommen. Dort steht es nämlich schon seit Juli 2006: http://wissen.schoelnast.at/beitraege/beitrag_2006-07-09.html

Answer (score 6):

> Im Deutschen lautet das Wort mit der längsten
>   Konsonantenbuchstabenfolge – wenn man nur Wörter mitzählt, die in
>   üblichen Wörterbüchern verzeichnet sind – vermutlich **Angstschweiß**
>   (fünf Konsonanten-Phoneme bzw. -Laute in Folge, die mit Hilfe von acht
>   Konsonantenbuchstaben dargestellt werden).

[Source](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konsonant)

> Deutschschweiz, Deutschschweizer[in], deutschschweizerisch,
>    Welschschweizer[in], welschschweizerisch,
>    Angstschweiß,
>    Geschichtsschreibung,
>    Rechtsschrift,
>    Unterrichtsschritt

[Source](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/die-woerter-mit-den-meisten-aufeinanderfolgenden-konsonanten)

Answer (score 3):

Ansonsten hätte ich noch Troeltzschschüler anzubieten, mit 9 Konsonanten. ernst Troeltzsch war liberaler Theologe im 19. und 20. Jh.

Answer (score 3):

Laut Duden *Sprache in Zahlen* (genauso wie laut [dieser Seite](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-woerter-mit-den-meisten-aufeinanderfolgenden-konsonanten)) ist **Borschtsch** das einzige einfache (also nicht zusammengesetzte oder abgeleitete) deutsche Wort mit acht aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonanten.

Wenn auch Zusammensetzungen berücksichtigt werden, findet man im Duden Band 1 – *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung* außerdem die folgenden Wörter mit jeweils acht aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonanten:

> - Deutschschweiz, Deutschschweizer[in], deutschschweizerisch
> - Welschschweizer[in], welschschweizerisch
> - Angstschweiß
> - Geschichtsschreibung
> - Rechtsschrift
> - Unterrichtsschritt

Das Dudenkorpus weist allerdings noch weitere Wörter mit acht aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonanten auf, die jedoch nicht im Duden Band 1 stehen, z. B.

> - angstschlotternd
> - Weihnachtsschmuck
> - nächtsschnellere
> - Kunstgeschichtsschreibung
> - Herbstschwimmfest

Answer (score 3):

Ich hätte eins mit sechs Konsonanten, von denen aber im Gegensatz zu vielen hier aufgeführten Beispielen **alle sechs getrennte Phoneme sind**!

> Selbstzweifel

Comment: Ich habe ja deswegen "vielen" und nicht "allen" geschrieben; Borschtschgschnas ist auch nur ein regionales Wort. Bei Wörtern, die mit `Herbst` beginnen wäre ich vorsichtig, weil das deutsche `r` meistens nicht konsonantisch ausgesprochen wird (sondern: Heɐ̯bst). Das Wort `Selbstzweifel` ist gängig und hat sechs echte konsonantische Phoneme.

Comment: Ah, da hat mein Gehirn das *alle* in Deinem Satz falsch eingelesen. Und das mit dem vokalischen *r* hatte ich ja auch schon angemerkt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich konnte noch ein Wort mit **8** Konsonanten in Folge finden:

> rechtsschwenkt!

Comment: Müsste aber, als Substantiv, Rechtsschwenk sein, oder rechtsschwenkt als Imperativ klein, oder?

Comment: @userunknown ja stimmt, Imperativ (wie in „rechtsschwenkt, marsch!”.  Aber da habe ich auch [diese Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/gross-und-kleinschreibung-von-zitaten-am-satzanfang) auch in betracht gezogen, so, irgendwie das Kleinschreiben war nicht so pflichtig, oder?

Answer (score 2):

For an "official" answer (of sorts), see the [Duden website.](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/die-woerter-mit-den-meisten-aufeinanderfolgenden-konsonanten)

Answer (score 0):

### Borschtschgschnas

- Gesamtlänge: 17 Buchstaben
- Enthaltene Konsonantenkette: *rschtschgschn*
- **Länge der Konsonantenkette: *13* Konsonanten**
- Aussprache des ganzen Wortes: [bɔʁʃtʃkʃnaːs]
- Phoneme der Konsonantenkette: [ʁ ʃ t ʃ k ʃ]
- **Anzahl der Phoneme in der Kette: *6* Phoneme**

Damit liegt »*Borschtschgschnas*« mit der Buchstabenanzahl vor allen anderen genannten Beispielen, und mit der Anzahl der Phoneme gleichauf mit »*Selbstzweifel*«, also in beiden Kategorien auf Platz 1.

Dazu ein Zitat eines Eintrages in meiner [Datenbank des nutzlosen Wissens](http://wissen.schoelnast.at/) (dort erschienen am 9. Juli 2006):

> »Angstschweiß« galt lange Zeit als jenes deutsche Wort, in dem die längste ununterbrochene Folge von Konsonanten (nämlich »ngstschw«) vorkommt. Tatsächlich enthalten aber auch Wörter wie »Rechtsschraube«, »Herbstschnee« und »Hirschschlögel« ebenfalls Ketten aus jeweils 8 Konsonanten.
>   »**Borschtsch**« (ein russischer Kohl-Eintopf) (enthält ebenfalls eine 8er-Kette) darf insofern als deutsches Wort gelten, als es sowohl im österreichischen Wörterbuch und auch im Duden zu finden ist.
>   Dasselbe gilt für das österreichische Wort »**Gschnas**«, (BRD-deutsch: »Kostümfest«), das im Wort »Faschingsgschnas« (für die Freunde aus meinem Lieblings-Ausland: »Fasnachtkostümfest«) auch eine Achter-Konsonantenkette bildet.
>
> Wenn man aber zu Ehren des russischen Kohl-Eintopfs ein Kostümfest veranstaltet, dann würde man das zumindest im deutschsprachigen Österreich ganz eindeutig als »**Borschtschgschnas**« bezeichnen, und kommt so zu einem sinnvollen, und in der deutschen Sprache verwendbaren Wort, das eine ununterbrochene Folge aus 13 Konsonanten (nämlich »rschtschgschn«) enthält.

<sup>([Link zum zitierten Beitrag](http://wissen.schoelnast.at/beitraege/beitrag_2006-07-09.html))</sup>

Comment: Rote Bete! Nicht Kohl ...