# Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Zitaten am Satzanfang

Tags: capitalization

Hier auf Stackexchange kommt es immer wieder vor, dass ein Wort, über das diskutiert wird, am Satzanfang steht. Es ist dann mittels Anführungszeichen oder anderer Marker herausgehoben, um es nicht semantisch mit auszuwerten. Allerdings werden dabei dann Wörter, die von Natur aus kleingeschrieben werden, kleingeschrieben.

> Tisch ist ein Nomen. *deshalb* ist ein Adverb.

Ich finde das extrem irritierend. Meiner Ansicht nach überwiegt die Großschreibung am Satzanfang. Es sollte also heißen

> Tisch ist ein Nomen. *Deshalb* ist ein Adverb.

- Wie ist die Regel dazu, wenn es denn eine gibt?

Comment: Ein paar Artikel, die das Thema nicht allgemein betrachten, sondern sich auf Spezialfälle beziehen. Imho, sollte es groß geschrieben werden. http://canoo.net/blog/2013/12/11/ein-apostroph-am-satzanfang-wie-gehts-weiter/ - http://canoo.net/blog/2010/08/05/adidas-canoo-der-spiegel-und-das-iphone/ - http://canoo.net/blog/2013/01/31/www-am-satzanfang/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In der amtlichen Regelung (zu finden auf [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf53-54.html?MenuId=OfficialSpelling131)) heißt es erst einmal:

> § 54 Das erste Wort eines Ganzsatzes schreibt man groß.

Danach kommen einige Hinweise, dazu gehört: Nach einem Doppelpunkt schreibt man groß.

Außerdem heißt es dort: "Das erste Wort der wörtlichen Rede schreibt man groß."

Ein Satz innerhalb von Parenthesen (das hier ist einer) gilt nicht als eigenständiger Satz und ist kleinzuschreiben.

5) Gliederungsangaben wie Ziffern, Paragrafen, Buchstaben gehören nicht zum nachfolgenden Ganzsatz; entsprechend schreibt man das folgende Wort groß.

… und letztlich noch: Auslassungspunkte, Apostroph oder Zahlen zu Beginn eines Ganzsatzes
gelten als Satzanfang; entsprechend bleibt die Schreibung des folgenden Wortes unverändert.

Die Beispiele, um die es dir hier geht, sind weniger Zitate (die fallen ja im Grunde unter wörtliche Rede und sind somit großzuschreiben), sondern vielmehr nur durch "Anführungszeichen" oder *kursive Schrift* hervorgehobene Begriffe (oder manchmal auch ganze Sätze).
Diese werden in der Regelung nicht erwähnt. Und wie ich gelernt habe, fällt alles, was nicht separat erwähnt wird unter die allgemeine Regel: folglich Großschreibung.

Vergleichbar ist auch die Fragestellung, ob Markennamen – welche außerhalb des Textflusses kleinzuschreiben sind – am Satzanfang großgeschrieben werden sollten. Dies wurde im [Blog von canoonet](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2010/08/05/adidas-canoo-der-spiegel-und-das-iphone/) diskutiert und das Fazit ist, dass es definitiv sinnvoll ist, aber aufgrund fehlender offizieller Vorschrift nicht zwingend sei.
Dies anwendend auf das Problem hier: Schreibe groß und toleriere Kleinschreibung.

Comment: Wieso sollte man Kleinschreibung tolerieren? Wer genau? Deutschlehrer?

Comment: Der ganze Ansatz gefällt mir nicht. "Amtlich", "zwingend", "keine Vorschrift"... da scheint jemand auf die Anmaßung der Kultusministerrunde hereingefallen zu sein, mit einer "neuen Rechtschreibung" die Sprachkultur zu ihrem Rechtsfeld zu machen. Das können sie für den Schulunterricht schon tun. Ansonsten ist jedoch die Kultur des Schreibens und des Schriftsatzes Eigentum der Sprachbenutzergemeinschaft. Ich würde mich da nicht den Ministerialbürokraten beugen. Was gute Praxis ist, findet man in entsprechenden Ratgebern. Und in gut gesetzten Büchern und Zeitschriften. "Amtlich"? Humbug!

Answer (score 5):

Wenn wir hier (und in vergleichbaren Fällen) über Worte u. Ä. diskutieren, würde ich die folgenden drei Fälle unterscheiden, von denen der letzte mit Abstand der häufigste ist, sich aber besser in Abgrenzung zu den anderen Fällen erklären lässt:

1. Es geht um die konkrete Schreibweise eines Wortes in einem konkreten Text:

   > In diesem Satz schreibe ich bewusst »produziren« statt »produzieren«, um ein Beispiel zu produziren.

   Hier geht es darum, das Geschriebene exakt wiederzugeben, also auch mit Groß- und Kleinschreibung, z. B.:

   > »ahber« werde ich am Anfang des folgenden Satzes schreiben und damit zwei Rechtschreibfehler in einem Wort begehen. ahber nur des Beispiels wegen.

   In so einem Fall setze ich auch immer Anführungszeichen und nutze niemals Kursivierung zur Abgrenzung des Wiedergegebenen. Damit bewege ich mich m. E. auch im Rahmen der Rechtschreibregeln, da ich etwas wörtlich wiedergebe, aber es sich nicht um wörtliche Rede handelt. Denn somit greift Paragraph § 89 (»Mit Anführungszeichen schließt man etwas wörtlich Wiedergegebenes ein.«), nicht aber § 54 (2) (»Das erste Wort der wörtlichen Rede schreibt man groß, […]«). Man kann darüber streiten, ob § 54 (»Das erste Wort eines Ganzsatzes schreibt man groß.«) greift, ich würde aber dagegen stimmen, da es sich bei dem hier Wiedergegebenen nicht um ein Wort im fraglichen Ganzsatz handelt, sondern erstmal nur um eine Buchstabenfolge (die auch tatsächlich kein Wort zu sein braucht).
2. Es geht nicht um ein Wort, sondern Buchstaben bzw. eine Buchstabenfolge:

   > *ih* steht nur in den folgenden Wörtern: *ihm, ihn, …*

   Hier ist es üblich, auch am Satzanfang nicht auf Großschreibung zu wechseln. Und auch wenn ich dazu keine offizielle Regel finden konnte, wird dies insofern durch das offizielle Rechtschreibregelwerk gedeckt, als dass ihm dieses Beispiel entstammt (S. 23, § 12).
3. Es geht ein Wort in einem allgemeineren Sinne (als Punkt 1), z. B.:

   > Das Verb dieses Satzes ist *ist.*
   >   Der Infinitiv des Verbs dieses Satzes ist *sein.*

   In so einem Fall könnte ich nach den offiziellen Regeln durch Anführungszeichen auszeichnen, muss es aber nicht. Um einen Wald von Anführungszeichen zu vermeiden, nutze ich in solchen Fällen lieber Kursivierung, wie es auch z. B. hier und in den Rechtschreibregeln üblich ist. Die Nutzung von Anführungszeichen fände hier nach § 94 statt und ist optional – ich könnte also sogar keine Auszeichnung verwenden (auch wenn dies in den meisten Fällen verwirrend wäre):

   > Olfaktorisch war sein neues Lieblingswort.

   In diesem Fall würde auch wohl niemand auf die Idee kommen, das Wort kleinzuschreiben.

   Aber mal ein schwierigeres Beispiel, das einen anderen Aspekt verdeutlicht:

   > Er schrieb durchgängig *nähmlich* statt *nämlich.*

   Wieso nutze ich hier keine Anführungszeichen bzw. wieso fällt dies nicht unter Punkt 1? Es hier nicht um eine konkrete Stelle im Text, sondern um die allgemeine Schreibung des Wortes *nämlich.* Dies wird vielleicht am ehesten klar, wenn man sich überlegt, dass sich die obige Aussage wohl auch die Fälle einschließen soll, in denen das Wort *nämlich* nicht am Satzanfang steht. Es handelt sich also ohnehin nicht um eine exakte Wiedergabe, sondern es geht um das Wort *nämlich* im Allgemeinen. Analog schriebe ich also auch:

   > *Nähmlich* statt *nämlich* schrieb er durchgängig.
   >   *Derentwegen* und *einander* sind meine Lieblingswörter.

   Und aus ähnlichen Gründen:

   > *Gehen* ist kein Hauptwort, sondern ein Zeitwort und muss daher kleingeschrieben werden.
   >   Aus unerklärlichen Gründen schrieb er *gehen* immer groß.

   Aber:

   > In jenem Satz muss »gehen« statt »Gehen« geschrieben werden.
   >   »kraft« ist hier tatsächlich korrekterweise kleingeschrieben.

Comment: Eigentlich – und das hätte ich schon in meiner Antwort erwähnen können –, wenn du wirklich ein Wort exakt so wiedergeben möchtest, wie es geschrieben wurde, einschließlich Groß- und Kleinschreibung, dann sollte man doch schlauerweise das Wort ins Satzinnere stellen. Letztlich ist es doch sehr verwirrend, wenn ein Satz mit einem kleinen Buchstaben anfängt, unabhängig davon, ob es richtig oder falsch ist.

Comment: @Em1: Dem stimme ich absolut zu, allerdings muss die Rechtschreibung auch auf so eine Frage eine Antwort wissen.

Comment: @Em1: Dreht das nicht nur das Problem dahingehend um, dass dann potenziell ein eigentlich kleinzuschreibendes Wort mit einem Großbuchstaben am Anfang im Satzinneren stehen könnte?

Answer (score 3):

Die Regel lautet ganz klar:

Das erste Wort eines Satzes ist mit einem großen Anfangsbuchstaben zu schreiben. Das gilt auch für Hervorhebungen:

> Ich möchte betonen, dass »**sich** betrinken« keine sinnvolle Freizeitbeschäftigung ist.
>   »**Sich** betrinken« ist, wie ich betonen möchte, keine sinnvolle Freizeitbeschäftigung.

Allerdings gilt immer auch »die oberste Direktive«:

**Sprache ist da, um verstanden zu werden.**

Daher würde ich, auch wenn es gegen die festgeschriebenen Regeln verstößt, Folgendes schreiben:

> Ich komme wieder auf den fraglichen Fall zurück. »**gehen**« ist kein Hauptwort, sondern ein Zeitwort und muss daher kleingeschrieben werden.

Comment: "Gehen" ist kein Zeitwort sondern ein Verb. Würdest du also auch "sich betrinken" eigentlich klein schreiben?

Comment: @Emanuel Ich glaube fast, dass er darauf hinaus will, dass es paradox erscheint, *gehen* großzuschreiben und im selben Satz zu behaupten, es würde kleingeschrieben.

Comment: @Em1... oh. Diesen Hintersinn im Beispiel hab' ich nicht bemerkt. Dann geb' ich mal plus 1, bin aber weder einverstanden, noch überzeugt. Hail king Capital.

Comment: @Emanuel: Worin genau besteht deiner Meinung nach der Unterschied zwischen einen Zeitwort und einem Verb? Ich habe in der Schule nämlich gelernt, dass »Verb« jenes Fremdwort ist, das man auch für das deutsche Wort »Zeitwort« verwenden kann. Die beiden Wörter sind also gleichbedeutende Synonyme. So steht es auch hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb

Comment: Ok, das scheint man in der Tat so zu nennen. Für mich ist ein Zeitwort ein Wort für Zeit... so wie "heute" oder "bald". Ich glaube, es ist sicherer Verb zu schreiben, wenn man Missverständnisse vermeiden will.

Comment: @Emanuel: Die Wörter »heute« und »bald« sind keine Zeitwörter, sondern Umstandswörter (Umstandswörter der Zeit, um genau zu sein). Hier ist eine gute Liste der Wortarten mit ihren lateinischen und deutschen Bezeichnungen: http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/Wortarten.htm

Comment: @HubertSchölnast.. mag schon sein. Ich empfehle trotzdem "Verb" da hier einige Nicht-Muttersprachler und Laien unterwegs sind. Ich halte den Begriff Zeitwort sowieso für verfehlt... genauso wie "Geschlechtswort"... das ist für Englisch einfach nur sinnfrei

Comment: Bei Interesse an »Zeitwort« versus »Verb«: [Warum heißen Verben “Zeitwort”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9610/1859)

Comment: Wieso setzt Du `sich betrinken` und `die oberste Direktive` in Anführungsstriche? Zudem ist dieses Herausheben des Wortes Gehen, welches seiner Funktion ein Verb zu sein gerade beraubt ist mitnichten ein Argument es kleinzuschreiben, denn gerade in seiner Funktion als Verb wird es auch am Satzanfang immer großgeschrieben. "Gehen wir noch einen trinken?"

Comment: @userunknown: "sich betrinken", wie auch "gehen", können hier Zitate aus einem anderen Schriftstück sein. Damit stellt sich die Frage, ob man nur den wörtlichen Inhalt, oder auch die ursprüngliche Schreibweise zitieren möchte.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich habe »sich betrinken« in Chevrons gesetzt, weil es ein Beispiel für ein wörtliches Zitat sein sollte. Bei »die oberste Direktive« habe ich es gemacht um diese Wortgruppe hervorzuheben. Siehe http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anführungszeichen erster und zweiter Satz. Im Übrigen hat O. R. Mapper recht: »sich betrinken« und »gehen« sollten Beispiel für wörtliche Zitate aus anderen Texten sein, wobei im Fall von »gehen« die Groß- bzw. Kleinschreibung wichtig ist, weshalb es paradox wäre, auf die Kleinschreibung zu pochen wenn man es im Zitat dann doch groß schreiben würde.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wörtliche Zitate einzelner Wörter sind aber ausgesprochen sinnlos, wenn auch eine zunehmende Unsitte.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich finde sie durchaus sinnvoll, aber man muss sie natürlich nicht verwenden, wenn man sich nie auf einzelne von anderen geschriebene Wörter beziehen möchte.

Comment: @userunknown: Was ist daran sinnlos, wenn ich durch ein Ein-Wort-Zitat darauf hinweisen will, dass das Wort »gehen« im Satz »Wir gehen fort« ein Verb ist, während »Gehen« in »Das Gehen bereitet ihm Schmerzen« ein Substantiv ist. »gehen« groß zu schreiben wäre im ersten der beiden Fälle paradox, wenn ich, wie jetzt gerade, hervorheben möchte, dass es falsch wäre dieses Wort groß zu schreiben. Daher habe ich »gehen« im vorangegangenen Satz absichtlich klein geschrieben, obwohl das einer Rechtschreibregel widerspricht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sich auf einzelne Wörter beziehen die andere verwendet haben ist noch kein Zitat. Ein Zitat ist eine Aussage die im Wortlaut wiedergegeben wird - nur ein einzelnes Wort wiederzugeben ist kein Zitat, auch nicht, wenn es feierlich in Anführungsstriche verpackt wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es ist nicht paradox. Lies den Text vor, und Du stellst fest, dass Du das Wort gehen am Satzanfang betonen musst wie einen Satzanfang. Deswegen schreibst Du es groß. Da Kleinschreibung alleine nicht betonbar ist muss der Inhalt über den Inhalt des Satzes und nicht über die Schreibung vermittelt werden. Wenn Du das Wort _zweisilbig_ schreibst lässt Du auch keine Silbe weg, um eine Paradoxie zu vermeiden.

Comment: @userunknown: Dann haben wir offenbar unterschiedliche Meinungen dazu, was ein Zitat darstellt. Lässt man die Anführungszeichen weg, fehlt die Kennzeichnung, dass es sich bei einem Bestandteil des Satzes um eine Wiedergabe handelt und es enstehen grammatikalisch groteske Konstruktionen wie "das Wort gehen am Satzanfang". Natürlich ist "das Wort 'gehen' am Satzanfang" gemeint (in der gesprochenen Sprache wird die Kennzeichnung ja auch durch entsprechende Betonung ersetzt). Und wenn ich mir Huberts Satz vorlese, stelle ich fest, dass ich "gehen" in Anführungszeichen entschieden anders ...

Comment: ... betonen würde als ein einfaches Vorkommen von "Gehen" am Satzanfang wie in "Gehen wir einkaufen!". Richtig, im Wort "zweisilbig" lässt man keine Silbe weg, weil es dabei auch gar nicht um die Schreibung geht. Ein besseres Beispiel wäre ein Wort, welches eigentlich falsch geschrieben ist, und auch so wiedergegeben werden soll. Im Satz "Er hat 'Fehlär' statt 'Fehler' geschrieben." wäre es durchaus paradox, das erste Vorkommen von "Fehler" so zu schreiben, wie man es schreiben würde, wäre es kein Zitat.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Im letzten Beispiel, das zweite 'Fehler' - ist das auch ein Zitat? Wer wird da zitiert? Als Wort, nicht als Verb, muss Gehen m.E. auch groß geschrieben werden. Beweis: Es kann ein Adjektiv dazugesetzt werden: Das fette Gehen ... .

Comment: @userunknown: "Wer wird da zitiert?" - Wahlweise das Lexikon, bzw. ein beliebiges Regelwerk, welches die richtige Schreibung enthält, oder der Sprecher selber, der die richtige Schreibweise wiedergibt, wie er sie selber verwendet hätte. "Als Wort, nicht als Verb" - diese Aussage ergibt keinen Sinn. Ein Verb ist natürlich auch ein Wort. Natürlich muss ein substantiviertes Verb stets mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnen (wenn es richtig geschrieben ist); davon bleibt die Schreibung eines zitierten, *nicht* substantivierten Verbs unberührt.

Comment: a) Es geht mir nicht um substantivierte Verben, sondern um den Gebrauch eines Wortes als Element der Sprache, wie das Beispiel "Das fette Gehen in Huberts Text" zeigen soll. Die Funktion des Wortes ist hier die eines Substantivs und hat nichts mit dem Gehen zu tun, welches eine olympische Disziplin sein könnte, aber dann kaum fett sein könnte. b) Wahlweise dies oder jenes wird zitiert? Etwas, was der Sprecher gesagt hätte, wenn er es verwendet hätte - also eben kein Zitat. Würde man so schreiben, dann könnte man Zitatzeichen in Texten nicht trauen. Das ist aber ihr Sinn.

Comment: @userunknown: Anführungszeichen verwendet man nicht nur für wörtliche Zitate, sondern auch für Hervorhebungen. Wenn O. R. Mapper das Wort »Fehler« in »Er hat 'Fehlär' statt 'Fehler' geschrieben.« in Anführungszeichen setzt, dann ist das kein Zitat, sondern eine Hervorhebung. Lies dazu bitte auch den zweiten Satz in http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anführungszeichen