# Warum heißen Verben "Zeitwort"?

Tags: terminology

Wie ich in einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/gross-und-kleinschreibung-von-zitaten-am-satzanfang/9603?noredirect=1#comment24762_9603) erfahren habe, nennt man im Deutschen Verben auch **Zeitwort**.

- Wieso?
- Ist das wirklich sinnvoll oder nur ein komischer Versuch Fremdwörter zu vermeiden?

Comment: Schön ist das Zitat auf der [Wikitionary-Seite](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zeitwort): „Es ist ein Unglück, daß wir im Deutschen Verbum mit Zeitwort übersetzt haben. Tatwort müßte es heißen, denn es gibt die Tat, die Handlung, das Ereignis wieder.“ In meinen Augen richtig sind Tuwort und Tätigkeitswort. Alle anderen Begriff sind nonsense.

Comment: "Tätigkeitswort" und "Tunwort" stoßen auch an ihre Grenzen, wenn man an Verben wie "abwarten", "wissen" oder "vergessen" denkt. Hier steckt weder eine Handlung, noch ein Ereignis dahinter.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg das ist so nicht richtig... *"abwarten"* ist auch ein tun. nämlich mit hinblick auf ein abgewartetes Ereignis nichts. aber bei wissen und vergessen stimme ich dir voll zu, obwohl beide auf ein vorheriges "tun" hinweisen..

Comment: `Tuwort` und `Tunwort` sollten nur zur didaktischen Reduktion eingesetzt werden. Der Standard ist `Verb` und sollte es auch bleiben.

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg Warum so kompliziert? Die Kopulaverben "sein", "werden" und "bleiben" sind doch schon tolle Beispiele für Verben, die keine Tätigkeiten ausdrücken (sodern eher Existenz)

Comment: @Em1 Auf Niederländisch heißt *Verb* eben "Tutwort", *werkwoord* (ok, *Arbeitswort* wäre die strenge, allerdings zu berschrenkende, Übersetzung).

Comment: @c.p. ... in Deutsch sagt man auch "Tunwort" aber das klingt extremst kindisch in meinen Ohren. Ich würde ja für Aktivitätswort plädieren, oder wenn das zu lang ist, dann Aktionswort.

Comment: Präsens, Imperfekt/Präteritum, Futur etc. sind Zeiten des Verbs.

Comment: @rogermue... gibt es auch "Zeiten des Adjektivs"?

Comment: @Emanuel Habe noch kein Adjektiv mit Zeiten gefunden.

Comment: @rogermue... ja genau ;). Deshalb ist "Zeiten des Verbs" auch ein bisschen leer.

Comment: In der Schule wurden Verben als Verben oder Tätigkeitswörter bezeichnet. Diese "Zeitwort" war mir vollig fremd bis meine Kinder das in den neuen Lehrplan hatten. Der Begriff ist damit regional unterschiedlich und wurde vom Schulsystem der gebrauchten Bundesländern übernommen.

Comment: Ich hab *gedacht*, dass diese Begriffe ab Mitte der Dreißigerjahre eingeführt worden wären. Dann hab ich im Dwds nachgeschlagen, und eine Quelle aus dem 17. Jahrhundert gesehen. Falls also jemand diese deutschen Grammatikbegriffschöpfungen einer bestimmten Partei zuschieben möchte, ist das als *urban Legend* abzulehnen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laut [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zeitwort) heißen Verben Zeitwörter, da sie Formen für die verschiedenen Tempora (Zeiten) aufweisen.
Man muss sie also je nach Zeit konjugieren. Aber ich weiß nicht, ob das der einzig wahre Grund ist.

Comment: Nach der Logik gibt es ja dann in Sprachen, deren Vergangenheit mittels Partikeln ausgedrückt wird, keine Verben... nichts gegen die Antwort an sich.

Comment: Aber nur weil Verben in Deutsch Zeitwörter sind, heißt das ja noch lange nicht, dass alle Zeitwörter auch Verben sind, insbesondere in anderen Sprachen.

Answer (score 10):

In deutscher Grammatik werden Verben auch "Zeitwörter" genannt, weil sie die einzigen Wörter sind, die abhängig von der Zeit flektiert werden können.

Dass das in anderen Sprachen nun mal nicht so ist, tut ja nichts zur Sache. Im Japanischen kann man sowohl "Verben" als auch eine Klasse von "Adjektiven" konjugieren. "Zeitwort" würde demnach sowohl auf Verben als auch auf bestimmte Adjektive zutreffen. (Genau deswegen nennt man diese Adjektive auch "adjectival verbs" also "adjektivische Verben" im Englischen.)

In einer anderen Sprache, in der keine Wortformen mit der Zeitform konjugieren, macht das Wort Zeitwort evtl. gar keinen Sinn. In einer deutschsprachigen Grammatik dieser Sprache benutzt man dann vielleicht besser den Begriff "Verb" (oder einen anderen, passenden Begriff).

Wie dem auch sei, in der deutschen Sprache macht der Begriff "Zeitwort" Sinn. Ob man den Begriff mag oder nicht, ist wieder ein anderes Thema. "Zeit" steht hier nämlich nicht für "hat *irgendetwas* mit Zeit zu tun“, sondern für "inflektiert je nach Zeitform/Tempus".

Comment: Verben sind die einzigen Wörter die konjugiert werden können. Ob Zeit oder nicht ist egal. Zudem halte ich es für angebracht, für derart grundlegende grammatische Einheiten, eben auch einheitliche Definitionen zu finden, die in jeder Sprache funktionieren. Und nicht zuletzt... es sollte dann doch schon "Zeitformwort" heißen.

Comment: Du darfst ja weiterhin "Verb" benutzen und "Zeitwort" ohne weitere Probleme ignorieren. Außerdem gibt es keine grammatische Einheiten, die in jeder Sprache funktionieren. Ich kann dir das Buch "The Language Instinct" von Steven Pinker empfehlen.

Comment: "Verben sind die einzigen Wörter die konjugiert werden können. Ob Zeit oder nicht ist egal.": Nomen inflektieren (deklinieren) je nach Fall.

Answer (score 6):

Der Begriff "Zeitwort" ist völlig korrekt und nicht unüblich. Verben heißen Zeitwörter, weil man mit ihnen die Zeit ausdrückt.

Edit:

"... hat man das Verbum auch Zeitwort genannt, weil es ihm unter allen Redetheilen allein eigenthümlich ist, durch bestimmte Formen die Zeit in ihrem Wechsel oder Flusse anzudeuten" (Grammatik der neuhochdeutschen Sprache)

Comment: Das stimmt leider nur bedingt. Morgen fahre ich nach Kölln. Womit habe ich jetzt Zeit ausgedrückt? Oder nimm einen Roman... "Er greift zu seinem Schwert." Heißt das, dass er es jetzt macht? Nein. Der Kontext gibt uns die Zeit. Sorry, aber dafür gibt's -1

Comment: "... hat man das Verbum auch Zeitwort genannt, weil es ihm unter allen Redetheilen allein eigenthümlich ist, durch bestimmte Formen die Zeit in ihrem Wechsel oder Flusse anzudeuten" (Grammatik der neuhochdeutschen Sprache)

Comment: Ok, aber es ist ja nun mal offensichtlich nicht so. Zeit kann durch alles mögliche ausgedrückt werden. "Von stolz erfüllt setzte Klaus den ersten Spatenstich." dann neues Kapitel "Der neue Mondflughafen war wirklich ein Meisterwerk." Hier etabliert die Nominalphrase, wann wir uns befinden. Das Verb ist in beiden Fällen Vegangenheit. Nimm dazu noch an, dass die Geschichte im Jahr 2300 spielt und das Verb hat garnichts mehr mit der Zeit zu tun. Mag sein, dass das die Begründung war, aber solange dein erster Satz steht, steht auch mein -1. Die Aussage ist einfach falsch.

Comment: +1 noch zwei Links die dies unterstützen: http://dwds.de/?qu=Zeitwort http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ03871

Comment: @Emanuel Es bestreitet ja keiner, daß man die Zeit auc noch anders andeuten oder ausdrücken kann. Das wichtige Wort hier ist "eigenthümlich". Und grammatisch haben eben nur die Zeitwörter Zeitformen.

Comment: @Ingo... was mich stört ist der Satz "Verben heißen Zeitwörter, weil man mit ihnen die Zeit ausdrückt." Das ist einfach zu unpräzise. Wenn das nicht wäre, hätte ich kein Problem mit der Antwort.

Answer (score 5):

**Wieso?**

Ich frage mal andersrum: Warum sollte es ausgerechnet »Verb« heißen? »Verb« ist vom lateinischen »verbum« abgeleitet und das heißt nichts anderes als »Wort«. Also ist streng genommen auch »Haus« ein Verb, ebenso wie »grün«, »gestern« und »wieso«.

Da sind »Tatwort«, »Tunwort« und »Tätigkeitswort« schon passendere Begriffe, auch wenn es Wörter aus dieser Gruppe gibt, die keine Tätigkeit ausdrücken (z.B. »heißen«: Im Satz »Ich heiße Hubert« wird ein Zustand ausgedrückt, keine Tätigkeit)

Mit »Zeitwort« soll betont werden, dass mit dieser Wortart das Verstreichen von Zeit ausgedrückt wird. Allerdings gilt hier dieselbe Kritik wie im Fall von »Tatwort«.

Ich verwende die Bezeichnung »Zeitwort«, weil ich diesen Begriff so in der Schule gelernt habe. Der Ausdruck »Zeitwort« stand nämlich zu meiner Volksschulzeit (1971-1975) im Lehrplan für österreichische Volksschulen, und er steht auch heute noch genau so dort: http://www.bmukk.gv.at/medienpool/3994/VS7T_Deutsch.pdf

---

**Ist das wirklich sinnvoll oder nur ein komischer Versuch Fremdwörter zu vermeiden?**

Ja, ich denke dass es sinnvoll ist. »Zeitwort« ist jedenfalls nicht unsinniger als »Verb« oder »Tatwort«.

Den Versuch Fremdwörter zu vermeiden finde ich generell nicht komisch. Warum sollte man, wenn man die deutsche Sprache beschreibt, dafür Begriffe verwenden, die nicht dieser Sprache entstammen?

Es ist durchaus sinnvoll, Fremdwörter parat zu haben, beispielsweise wenn man die Grammatiken verschiedener Sprachen vergleichen möchte. Vergleicht man z.B. Englisch und Deutsch, dann will man sicherlich nicht ständig zwischen »noun« und »Hauptwort« wechseln, wenn es dafür das Fremdwort »Substantiv« gibt.

Aber wenn ich mich in deutscher Sprache über die deutsche Sprache unterhalten will, warum soll ich dafür lateinische Wörter verwenden, wenn es gut eingeführte deutsche Wörter gibt?

Liste der deutschen Wortarten in deutscher Sprache:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatikbegriffe_im_Deutschen#Wortarten

Comment: Einen Vorteil hat die Verwendung von Fremdwörtern schon: Man kommt deutlich seltener auf die Idee, dass sie selbsterklärend wären, was ja gerade das Problem von *Zeitwort* und auch *Tätigkeitswort* ist. Ja, *Verb* bedeutet wortwörtlich genommen einfach nur *Wort,* aber das haben diejenigen, die sich mit diesem Begriff zurechtfinden müssen, (also vor allem Schüler) in der Regel nicht vor Augen. Und vor allem für diese ist es wichtig, missverständiche Bezeichnungen (also *Zeitwort, Tuwort,* usw.) zu vermeiden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, das schreibt auch [Adelung](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=Adelung&lemid=DZ00374): „Da der Begriff eines Verbi sehr zusammen gesetzt ist, so wird sich wohl nicht leicht ein schickliches Deutsches Wort ausfindig machen lassen, welches auch nur den Hauptbegriff mit Präcision und Geschmack ausdruckte, daher man lieber den Lateinischen Ausdruck beybehält, bey welchem man an die Wortbedeutung nicht mehr denkt, daher man jeden Begriff damit verbinden kann.“

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Dein letztes Argument gilt auch umgekehrt: Ja, Zeitwort bedeutet wortwörtlich genommen ein Wort das mit Zeit zu tun hat, aber das haben diejenigen, die sich mit diesem Begriff zurechtfinden müssen, (also vor allem Schüler) in der Regel nicht vor Augen. Und vor allem für diese ist es wichtig, missverständiche Bezeichnungen (also Verb) zu vermeiden.

Comment: Darf ich fragen, wie du darauf kommst, das der Begriff "Zeitwort" das "verstreichen" betonen soll? In einer anderen Antwort heißt es, es sei der Tempora wegen. Wörter wie "explodieren, knallen, springen, schmeißen,..." haben wohl kaum einen Fokus auf dem Verstreichen von Zeit. Nach der Logik ist dann auch "später" ein Zeitwort, denn es unterstreicht das Verstreichen von Zeit. Mit "tunwort" habe ich kein Problem. Mit "Zeitwort" schon. Und bloß weil es früher so gehandhabt wurde, heißt das nicht, das es gut ist.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Doch, die meisten Schüler werden automatisch die Zusammensetzung von *Zeitwort* erkennen und naturgemäß erwarten, dass damit ein Wort gemeint ist, das irgendwie Zeit darstellt (also z. B. *gestern, jetzt* oder *Montag)* – genauso wie ein *Eigenschaftswort* Eigenschaften darstellt und *Türgriff* für den Griff einer Tür steht. Obendrein ist der Vorteil von Erbwörtern gegenüber Fremdwörtern doch gerade, dass sie direkt verständlich sind. Wenn Du dem Begriff *Zeitwort* diese Eigenschaft absprichst, geht damit auch sein einziger vermeindlicher Vorteil verloren.

Answer (score 4):

Ich zitiere aus Ludwig Reiners Stilfibel (1963):

> .. die wichtigste Wortart ist das **Tätigkeits-** oder **Zeitwort**. [...] Die Bezeichnung Zeitwort ist ungeschickt, aber wir können sie nicht ändern. Der lateinische Name für das Zeitwort ist **Verbum** (Mehrzahl Verben oder Verba).

Comment: Begründet Reimers auch, warum er den Begriff Zeitwort für ungeschickt hält oder wird hier nur nachgeplappert?

Comment: Nein, sonst hätte ich das mitgeliefert. Allein der Umfang der Diskussion hier und die Umgebung des Kommentars, der die Frage ausgelöst hat (auch Temporaladverben könnte man gut *Zeitwort* nennen) spricht für die Aussage. Den Zusammenhang von Nachplappern verstehe ich nicht: wer plappert wem nach?

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde "Zeitwort" überhaupt nicht ungeschickt. Im Gegenteil. Der Begriff sagt etwas Wesentliches über diese Wortart aus, es kann, wie bereits gesagt, verschiedene Zeiten (Präsens, Präteritum, Futur etc) ausdrücken.

Wenn in lateinischer Terminologie diese Wortart nur verbum genannt wurde, so war damit nicht "Wort" im allgemeinen Sinn gemeint, sondern "die wichtigste Wortart des Satzes", die von unten durch das Subjekt (das Daruntergelegte) getragen und oben vom Objekt (das Daraufgelegte) bedeckt wird.

Verbum ist auch von der Wortbildung her gesehen wohl die wichtigste Wortart, da die meisten Substantive von Verben abgeleitet werden.

Comment: Wörter wie "bald" "spät" oder "morgen" drückenauch Zeit aus. Sie drücken sogar NUR Zeit aus. Wenn das das Kriterium ist, damit Zeitwort ein guter Name ist, dann sollten die auch Zeitwort heißen.

Comment: Das Wesentliche der Zeitwörter ist, dass sie verschiedene Zeiten ausdrücken können, dass es ein Zeitensystem gibt. Das hat mit Zeitadverbien ja überhaupt nichts zu tun.

Comment: Dann haben also Sprachen, die nicht konjugieren keine Verben?

Comment: Was hat der deutsche Grammatikbegriff mit anderen Sprachen zu tun wie Japanisch, die ein ganz anderes Verbsystem haben ?  Nichts. Schon die Fragestellung ist ein Fehlschluss.

Comment: Also, Verben sind, soweit ich das sehen kann, eine ziemlich universelle Sache. Klar geht es auch ohne, aber die meisten Sprachen machen es mit. Da wäre es gut, wenn man überall so ca. das gleiche damit meint. Deshalb ist eine Definition als "Wort, das Zeiten ausdrückt" wahnsinnig kontraproduktiv, da diese Wortart dann in zahlreichen Sprachen nicht existiert.

Comment: Schön wär's, aber wir haben nicht einmal für Latein, Deutsch, Französisch und Englisch einheitliche Grammatikbegriffe. Grammatikbegriffe , die für alle Sprachen der Welt passen, wird es wohl kaum geben, dazu sind Sprachen zu verschieden. Der Grammatikbegriff Verben wird bei Japanisch geradezu problematisch. Und welchen Sinn hat es schon Schulanfängern lateinische Wörter an den Kopf zu schmeißen. Man muß das auch deutsch sagen können.  Unsere Grammatikbegriffe sind nicht als Universalbegriffe für die Sprachen der Welt gedacht, sondern für Deutsch.

Comment: Schon klar, aber innerhalb der Deutschen Sprache sollten sie für möglichst viele Sprchen anwendbar sein. Wie willst du dich denn dann zum Beispiel mit einem Deutschen über Chinesisch unterhalten?  Würdest du dann das Japanische Wort für diese Wortart wählen? Wohl kaum. Den Begriff "Zeitwort" kannst du aber auch nicht nehmen, denn er macht für diese Sprache keinen Sinn. Ergo... vielleicht ist es einfach kein guter Begriff, da er den Kern des Wortes nicht trifft. Verb ist nicht besser, aber zumindest "leer" (nicht automatisch vorkonnotiert, wie "Zeitwort")

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of "Zeitwort" is "time word."

Verbs are "time words" insofar as they deal with the past, present, and future (tenses).

Wörtlich ist ein Zeitwort ein "time word."

Zeitwörter sind "time words" insofern, als sie Vergangenheit, Präsens und Futur behandeln.