# Wann Anführungsstriche, wann kursiv?

Tags: quotes

In der deutschen Wikipedia sehe ich, dass manche Wörter *kursiv* und manche in „Anführungsstrichen“ gesetzt werden.

[Beispiel:](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haus#Haus_als_Rechtsbegriff)

> ...Das Wort *Haus*, ursprünglich „Schutz“ (wie Gehäuse), dann
>   „Wohnstatt“ (in hausen), heute „Wohngebäude“ ist schon in den
>   Frühzeiten des Schrifttums auch als Rechtsbegriff üblich...

Hier wird also:

- "Haus" kursiv gesetzt
- "Schutz", "Wohnstatt", "Wohngebäude" in Anführungsstrichen gesetzt

**Meine Fragen:**

Zufall oder Absicht?  (Sicher Absicht). Wenn Absicht: Nach welcher Regel?

Comment: Auf die Schnelle: Vielleicht hilft dir [dies hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/9609/2594) weiter.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Etwas, danke! Ich hab's mal durchgelesen und kämpfe jetzt noch damit das zu verstehen. Auf jeden Fall ist das glaube ich die Antwort, ich muss sie mir "nur" noch (*nur* noch?) erarbeiten.

Comment: Wenn Wikipedia eigene Regeln hat, dann musst Du das dort nachfragen. Wir beantworten Fragen zu Regeln der dt. Sprache - nicht zu Regeln irgendwelcher Vereine.

Comment: @userunknown: Selbst wenn es nur die Regel eines Vereins ist, ist es doch sicher eine gerechtfertigte Frage, was diesen Verein zu dieser Regel veranlasst hat oder ob diese oder ähnliche Regeln noch von anderen angewandt werden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Wer soll das denn wissen? War hier jemand dabei, als die sich ihr Regelwerk gaben? Nein. Also ermuntert die Frage nur zu amateurhaften Spekulationen. Nach anderen Vereinen mit ähnlichen Regeln wurde nicht gefragt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich hab da mal was gefunden:

> [...]
>
> In einem Text, den man benutzt und in dem man nach­schlägt, zum
> Bei­spiel in einem Wör­ter­buch, gibt es viele Mög­lich­keiten des
> Aus­zeich­nens.
>
> In Lesetexten, vor allem Zei­tungs­arti­keln und Roma­nen, erlau­ben
> die Re­geln der Kunst der deutsch­spra­chigen Schrift­setzerei nur das
> An­füh­rungs­zeichen und die Kur­sivie­rung. Fettdruck,
> Unter­strei­chen und Sper­ren sind im Fließ­text als
> Aus­zeich­nungs­met­ho­den nicht zu­läs­sig, ebenso Kapi­täl­chen und
> Ver­sa­lien.
>
> Stehen einem beide Met­ho­den zur Ver­fügung, zei­gen
> An­füh­rungs­zei­chen laute oder spre­chende Anführung an, die
> Kur­sivie­rung ist da­ge­gen leise. Auch einfache An­führunsg­zei­chen
> sind leise.
>
> ```
> "Platz da!" rief Superman und stürmte durch die Tür.
> Wörter wie *schon*/'schon' kann man immer strei­chen.
> ```
>
> [...]

[Quelle](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php)

Ich hoffe das hilft.

Comment: Vielen Dank, das ist für mich eine sehr gute Erklärung.

Answer (score 4):

Kursive Schrift impliziert *hervorheben*. Also, auf ähnliche Weise, wie man fett gedruckte Schrift oder Unterstreichen benutzen würde. Kursive Schrift ist neben fett und unterstrichen mit unter die schwächste form der Hervorhebung.

Im Unterschied dazu, wird mit Anführungstrichen *nie* hervorgehoben! Anführungstriche werden immer dann benutzt, wenn das Wort in seinem wörtlichen Sinn gemeint ist. Das gilt im Normalfall für jeden Sachverhalt, aber um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden, kann man dies mit Anführungszeichen nochmal deutlich machen. *Darüberhinaus, gibt es natürlich die Funktion der Kennzeichnung von wörtlicher Rede...*

Kursive Schrift kann wegen der guten Lesbarkeit auch bei längeren Texten verwendet werden, so z.B. bei Fußnoten, etc.

Am einfachsten kann man die Benutzung von Anführungstrichen die einen wörtlichen Sachverhalt beschreiben an diesem Dialog aufzeigen:

> **Alice:** Sag mal was...
>
> **Bob:** Was.
>
> **Alice:** Du sollt nicht "was" sagen, sondern *was sagen*!

Dazu sollte man noch sagen, das ich bei mehreren Fällen Anführungszeichen gesehen habe, die genau zum hervorheben oder betonen benutzt wurden:

> Bitte die Klingel "nicht" benutzen!

Das war an einem Schild in einem Laden. Hierbei ist die Benutzung von Anführungszeichen völlig falsch. Zum hervorheben/betonen benutzt man am besten entweder kursiv oder fett. Unterstrichen ist hingegen eine Geschichte für sich...

Comment: Sehr anschaulich beschrieben, sehr sympathisch. Herzlichen Dank! (und sehr cooles Profilbild!)

Comment: Anführungszeichen werden nicht nur benutzt, wenn etwas im wörtliche Sinn gemeint ist. Sie können auch verwendet werden, wenn etwas lediglich als Bezeichnung dient, tatsächlich aber etwas anderes gemeint ist.

Comment: @Toscho Die Funktionen sind so gesehen undendlich viele. Für Ironie (*Oh, wie "lustig"...*) , Beschriftung ("Rauchen verboten"-Schild), all dies kann man mit Anführungszeichen machen. Hab aber versucht den Beitrag am Thema zu halten...

Comment: @polemon Sehr aufklärend, aber was ist mit Eigennamen (und deren Abkürzungen) / Personennamen? Die Frage bezieht sich explizit auf die Verwendung in fachlichen Texten. Danke!

Answer (score 2):

Man muss ja unterscheiden zwischen einem Wort (der Zeichenkette), dem, was es bedeutet (der Idee, die in unserem Kopf entsteht, wenn wir das Wort hören) und dem, was dadurch bezeichnet wird (z.B. ein physikalischer Gegenstand, der aus Backsteinen besteht).

Es hat sich eingebürgert, dass man, wenn man über das Wort spricht, dieses kursiv schreibt. Spricht man über seine Bedeutung, verwendet man (oft) Anführungsstriche. Spricht man über das, was es bezeichnet, lässt man alle Dekorationen weg, denn dann sind wir auf der Objektebene und sagen "Das Haus wurde aus Backsteinen gebaut.".

Der Beispielsatz aus Wikipedia will also sagen, dass das Wort *Haus* die Bedeutung hat, die früher "Gehäuse" hatte, nämlich Schutz bieten.

Comment: Das klingt plausibel, besten Dank!