# "schnell" ist ein Adjektiv. – schnell am Satzanfang groß oder klein?

Tags: adjective, spelling, capitalization, quotes

> „schnell“ ist ein Adjektiv.

Muss ich das Wort *schnell* in diesem Kontext, also am Satzanfang, aber hinter Anführungszeichen, großschreiben? Ich zitiere ja nicht, sondern nutze die Anführungszeichen, um ein Wort, welches normalerweise kleingeschrieben wird, hervorzuheben.

Welche Regelungen liegen hier zu Grunde?

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Es gibt eine [Tour] der Seite. Weitergehende Fragen, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [Help].

Comment: Anführungsstriche weg und *schnell* groß. Videotutorial: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php

Comment: @userunknown Vielleicht sollten wir aus den Anführungszeichen eine eigene Frage machen. Bis dahin wäre es aber hilfreich, wenn Du angeben könntest, wo in Deiner Quelle Belege für Deine beiden Aussagen zu finden sind. Ich habe keine Zeit, mir 74min Video anzusehen. Im Text habe ich zur Frage der Großschreibung nichts gefunden und hinsichtlich der Anführungszeichen eher ein Argument, sie zu setzen: "Um an­zuzei­gen, daß über das Wort ge­spro­chen wird und nicht über das Ding hin­ter dem Wort, zeich­net man dieses Wort aus."

Comment: @Matthias: Im Satz "Schnell ist ein Adjektiv" kann es nicht um Phänomene der Fortbewegung gehen; der Kontext liefert eine eindeutige Interpretation so dass keine Auszeichnung benötigt wird. Da Auszeichnungen immer eine Störung des Leseflusses sind (sonst würden sie nicht funktionieren) lässt man sie da, wo man kann, möglichst weg. Sie sollen das Lesen befördern, nicht behindern. Btw. habe ich nicht die Zeit 74 Min. Video zu transkribieren.

Comment: @userunknown "Schnell ist ein Adjektiv [Seite umblättern] von einem Substantiv abgeleitet, wenn man die richtigen Regeln anwendet."

Comment: @Matthias: Und an welcher Stelle versteht man den Kontext, wenn es mit Anführungsstrichen geschrieben wurde? Wenn man *abgeleitet* gelesen hat. Und wenn keine Anführungsstriche stehen? Auch.

Comment: Wenn nicht eine Dublette, dann zumindest verwandt: [Groß- und Kleinschreibung von Zitaten am Satzanfang](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9592/2594)

Comment: Matthias hat recht. Man müsste hier innehalten und den Satz noch einmal rekapitulieren, und das muss auf jeden Fall vermieden werden. Übrigens ist Belles Lettres ein bisschen heuchlerisch. Sie zeichnen auch aus, wenn man es durch den Kontext auch verstünde. Ausgedachtes, aber oft so vorkommendes Beispiel: Das Substantiv _Tag_ ist im Ursprung der, der hell macht.

Comment: Ich würde das Beispiel unbedingt so ändern: *"Schnell" ist ein Adjektiv und muss daher klein geschrieben werden* ;)

Comment: Man muss dem Leser nicht unterstellen ein Idiot zu sein, der das Wort einmal großgeschrieben sieht, und fortan denkt, es müsse ab sofort immer großgeschrieben werden.

Answer (score 7):

Im Grunde gilt der § 54 der [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf):

> § 54: Das erste Wort eines Ganzsatzes schreibt man groß.

Nun, das alleine sagt vielleicht noch nicht viel aus. Es folgen Präzisierungen:

> 1. Wird die nach einem Doppelpunkt folgende Ausführung als Ganzsatz verstanden, so schreibt man das erste Wort groß, zum Beispiel: […]
> 2. Das erste Wort der wörtlichen Rede schreibt man groß, zum Beipsiel: […]
> 3. Folgt dem wörtlich Wiedergegebenen der Begleitsatz oder ein Teil von ihm, so schreibt man das erste Wort nach dem abschließenden Anführungszeichen klein, zum Beispiel: […]
> 4. Das erste Wort von Paranthesen schreibt man klein, wenn es nicht nach einer anderen Regel großzuschreiben ist, zum Beispiel: […]
> 5. Gliederungsangaben wie Ziffern, Paragraphen, Buchstaben gehören nicht zum nachfolgenden Gliedsatz; entsprechend schreibt man das folgende Wort groß. Dies gilt auch für Überschriften, Werktitel und dergleichen. Beispiele: […]
> 6. Auslassungspunkte, Apostroph oder Zahlen zu Beginn eines Ganzsatzes gelten als Satzanfang; entsprechend bleibt die Schreibung des folgenden Wortes unverändert. Dies gilt auch für Überschriften, Werktitel und dergleichen. Beispiele: […]

Explizit wird hierbei nur die wörtliche Rede genannt; wäre *schnell* ein Zitat, wäre es in deinem Beispiel nach § 54 (2) zweifellos groß zu schreiben.

Ich denke aber dennoch, dass *schnell* trotz der Anführungszeichen groß geschrieben werden muss. Denn vor Allem die Präzisierungen (4), (5) und (6) scheinen anzudeuten, dass Großschreibung der Normalfall zu sein hat, von dem man nur in bestimmten Ausnahmefällen abweichen darf. Ganz nach der guten alten Regel »Ober sticht Unter« wäre ich also für:

> »**S**chnell« ist ein Adjektiv.

Schließlich ist der Satz nur *mit* dem Wort *schnell* ein kompletter Ganzsatz.

Comment: also nochmal auf den punkt gebracht: laut den regeln muss der erste buchstabe eines ganzsatzes _immer_ und ohne ausnahme groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: @anion 'tschuldigung, aber "ohne Ausnahme" ist sicher falsch. ... und wenn Du den Absatz 6 aus der zitierten Regel mal komplett gelesen hättest, wüsstest Du auch, warum.

Comment: @anion: Warum tust du nicht selbst, was du da vorbetest? Du schreibst da über Rechtschreibregeln, wendest sie aber nicht an. Wie glaubwürdig ist das?

Comment: hi! wie wörter in bestimmten fällen formal korrekt geschrieben werden, ist gegenstand dieser diskussion. die anwendung der regeln, ist eine andere sache. die diskussion, dass menschen im internet oft alles klein schreiben (so wie auch ich das mache), und andere das wiederum nicht angemessen finden, ist ein anderes thema und wurde schon oft genug ausdiskutiert.
die frage ist, warum man dann oft nur kleinschreibung kritisiert und nicht konsequenter weise unabhängig vom thread-thema auch alle anderen arten von fehlern. ferner kann kleinschreibung als teil der sprachökonomie angesehen werden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich kann über das amtliche Regelwerk Stunden schwadronieren und trotzdem vehemt den einzigen klein schreiben und _klein schreiben_ auseinander schreiben.

Comment: @anion: Sorry, ich habe deinen Kommentar zwar gesehen, aber nicht gelesen. Was immer du mir sagen wolltest ist nicht bei mir angekommen, denn eine so unstrukturierte Wörter-Wurst kann ich nicht lesen. Ich brauche die Großbuchstaben, um Satzanfänge und Substantive zu erkennen.

Answer (score 5):

Der in [Jans Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32343/schnell-ist-ein-adjektiv-schnell-am-satzanfang-gro%C3%9F-oder-klein/32345#32345) schon erwähnte [$54 der Amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf53-54.html) sollte die maßgebliche Regelung sein, geht aber auf diesen konkreten Fall nicht ein. Die dort in Absatz 6 erwähnten Apostrophe und Auslassungspunkte gehen aber zumindest in diese Richtung. Entsprechend schreibt der Duden in seiner [Auslegung der Regeln](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K96):

> Ein mit Anführungszeichen oder anderer Schriftart gekennzeichnetes zitiertes Wort bleibt ebenfalls häufig unverändert.
>
> - „von" ist eine Präposition

(Kurioserweise ohne Punkt am Ende, aber der Zusammenhang legt doch nahe, dass es um ganze Sätze geht.)

Die Gesellschaft für Deutsche Sprache hat dazu auch noch einen [Kommentar](https://gfds.de/kleinschreibung-am-satzanfang/) veröffentlicht:

> Der frühere Rechtschreib-Duden hatte übrigens zwei weitere Beispiele für diese Sondergruppe der Orthographie parat (siehe 20. Auflage, 1991, R 78): ... Und weiterhin: »Ein am Satzanfang mit Anführungszeichen, anderer Schriftart o. ä. gekennzeichnetes zitiertes Wort wird klein geschrieben, wenn es auch sonst [!] klein geschrieben wird: ›von‹ ist eine Präposition. jedermann schreibt man mit zwei n.« Die Rechtschreibreform hat an diesem Regelteil prinzipiell nichts geändert.

Also: eher (der Duden schränkt ja auch ein: "häufig") klein schreiben. Es gibt sogar Fälle, denen sonst der Sinn abhanden käme:

> "fett" ist ein Adjektiv, "Fett" hingegen ein Substantiv.

Solange Du selbst der Autor bist, würde ich aber empfehlen, möglichst einen Satzbau zu verwenden, der das Problem vermeidet, weil das Leser-Auge doch stark an Großschreibung am Satzanfang gewöhnt ist. Also z.B.

> "Fett" ist ein Substantiv, "fett" hingegen ein Adjektiv.

Aber nicht immer geht das.

Übrigens, weil diese Frage in den Kommentaren auftauchte: Auch die Verwendung der Anführungszeichen ist für diesen Fall geregelt. In seiner [Rechtschreibregel 8](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/anfuehrungszeichen) schreibt der Duden:

> Anführungszeichen können vor und hinter Wörtern oder Textstücken stehen, die hervorgehoben werden sollen <§ 94>.
>
> Dazu gehören:
>
> 1. Wörter oder Wortgruppen (z. B. Sprichwörter, Äußerungen), über die man eine Aussage machen will

In den Beispielen hier geht es ja jeweils darum, eine Aussage über ein Wort zu treffen. Manchmal ist das aus dem Zusammenhang ersichtlich (wohl auch deshalb ist es als Kann-Regel formuliert), manchmal ist die Unterscheidung aber auch notwendig:

> "kurz" ist kurz und somit autologisch. "zweisilbig" hat hingegen nicht zwei, sondern drei Silben und ist somit heterologisch. Die Frage, ob "heterologisch" heterologisch ist, ist Gegenstand der [Grelling-Nelson-Antinomie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grelling-Nelson-Antinomie).

Comment: In deinem Beispiel finde ich die erste Variante ‘ “fett“ ist ein Adjektiv, “Fett" hingegen ein Substantiv.‘  klarer, weil es jeden Zweifel ausräumt, ob 'Fett' großgeschrieben wurde, weil es am Satzanfang steht, oder ob es etwas mit der Bedeutung des Satzes zu tun hat.

Comment: Wenn es so auf die Schreibung ankommt, dann kann man den Text nicht mehr vorlesen.

Comment: Wenn dass amtliche Regelwerk diesen Sonderfall nicht behandelt, dann kommt im besten Fall die allgemeine Regel zum Tragen, aber sicher keine Regelung der alten Rechtschreibung. Die amtliche Rechtschreibung ist keine Fortführung der alten, die auf deren Regeln aufbaut, sondern kann (und soll ja auch) gelernt werden, als wäre sie aus dem Nichts entstanden.

Answer (score 2):

Rein aus dem Gefühl heraus würde ich sagen, dass es vom vorhergehenden Satzzeichen abhängt, ob ein Wort groß geschrieben wird, unabhängig davon, ob es innerhalb von Anführungszeichen steht, oder nicht.

Wenn "schnell" das erste Wort in einem Zitat ganz am Anfang eines Textes ist, so ist es auch das erste Wort des Textes insgesamt und muss groß geschrieben werden. Ebenso, wenn es nach einem Punkt oder Doppelpunkt steht.

Nur wenn das Zitat ein unvollständiger Satz ist, z.B. einer, der einen Satz außerhalb des Zitats zu Ende führt, müsste man es klein schreiben, wie in diesem Beispiel:

> Der Minister sagte, man müsse "schnell zu einer Lösung kommen".

Hier geht der Satz nahtlos in das Zitat über, also steht "schnell" technisch gesehen nicht am Anfang eines Satzes, und muss somit klein geschrieben werden.

Comment: Dir auch servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Auch für dich der kurze Hinweise auf die [Tour] und das [Help], wobei dir letzteres alle Fragen beantwortet, die erstere offenlässt.

Comment: Im Grunde ist das eine sehr schöne erste Antwort, doch wie du an meiner Antwort sehen kannst, muss dein Ministerbeispiel lauten: »Der Minister sagte, man müsse ›Schnell zu einer Lösung kommen.‹«

Comment: @Jan: Da bin ich anderer Meinung. Mein Beispiel entspricht dem, was Du aus den amtlichen Regeln unter Punkt 3 zitiert hast. Die wörtliche Rede ist hier kein vollständiger Satz und wird erst durch die vorangehende indirekte Rede zu einem. Also darf man hier "schnell" nicht groß schreiben.

Comment: Punkt 3 bezieht sich auf Fälle wie »Man muss schnell zu einer Lösung kommen«, **s**agte der Minister. (Das geht aus den offiziellen Beispielen auch ganz schön hervor. Die wirklich komplizierten Fälle wie deinen haben sie natürlich nicht explizit aufgeführt, aber das ist mir schon öfters aufgefallen …)

Comment: Das ist kein Zitat, deswegen sind hier die Anführungsstriche falsch. Wenn Du schreibst, der Minister sagt, man müsse schnell zu einer Regelung kommen, kann es keine direkte Rede sein. Direkte Rede wäre: Der Minister sagte: "Man muss schnell zu einer Lösung kommen". Ein neuer Satz sollte meines Erachtens immer groß geschrieben werden, schon um den Verdacht zu zerstreuen, der wahrgenommene Punkt davor sei eine Bildschrirmverschmutzung. Anführungsstriche sind auch in 90% der Fälle ffalsch und können mit Gewinn gestrichen werden. Einzelne Wörter sind eh keine Zitate. Vorgelesen hört man auch …

Comment: … den Großbuchstaben nicht. Schnell ist ein Adjektiv und steht auch sonst gerne am Satzanfang, wo es auch nicht kleingeschrieben wird, Adjektiv hin oder her. Schnell belegen wir noch diese Tatsache. Würde die Wortart eine Rolle spielen bräuchte es keine Regel zur Großschreibung am Satzanfang. Im Satz: "Schnell ist ein Adjektiv." sind Anführungsstriche überflüssig, weil es keine Mehrdeutigkeit gibt, die vermieden werden kann. Die Kleinschreibung schützt einen auch nicht vor einer möglichen Fehlinterpretation.

Comment: Ein weiteres Beispiel aus den Medien, wo das erste Wort Zitat innerhalb eines Satzes klein geschrieben wird:  _"Ein-Satz-Formulierungen" über Zugehörigkeit seien immer problematisch, besonders wenn es um „so heikle Dinge“ gehe, wie die Religion, sagte Gauck._ [Quelle](http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/die-geschichte-eines-satzes-der-islam-gehoert-zu-deutschland.1895.de.html?dram:article_id=308696)

Comment: @Iris: Ein gutes Beispiel für ein Pseudozitat. Was hat Gauk denn jetzt gesagt? "Ein-Satz-Formulierungen so heikle Dinge"? Wohl kaum. Was dokumentiert jetzt das Zitat? Dass er die Phrase "so heikle Dinge" benutzt hat, und nicht "solch schwierige Sachen"? Wo ist der Informationsgehalt? Auch Dir empfohlen, das Videotutorial: belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php

Comment: @usee unknown, 'heikel' und 'schwierig' haben durchaus unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Und wenn dann eine andere Zeitung ihm womöglich das Synonym 'gefährlich' in den Mund legt...

Comment: Ich beobachte mit Staunen, wie auf einer Seite für Sprachexperten keiner einen Anfall bekommt, wenn er Konjunktiv 1 und eine kleine Beimengung Anführungszeichen serviert bekommt. Ich kann da nur user unknowns Vorschlag aufnehmen: Belles Lettres lesen und aha sagen.

Comment: @deponensvogel Einen _Anfall bekommen_ wegen anderer Auffassungen zum Sprachgebrauch? Nicht auf StackExchange. Hier gilt [Be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Matthias Ich bin ein Freund der Übertreibung. Sprachgebrauch würde ich Interpunktion aber nicht nennen. Wobei manche Leute tatsächlich notorisch die Anführungszeichen in die Luft deuten müssen.

Comment: @Iris: Darum geht es ja nicht. Man muss nicht die Wortwahl variieren, wenn man zur indirekten Rede greift. Entweder direkte Rede: Der Minister sagte: "Man muss schnell zu einer Lösung kommen". Oder indirekte Rede: Der Minister sagte, man müsse schnell zu einer Lösung kommen. Dass er nicht *rasch* gesagt hat ergibt sich auch bei indirekter Rede. Dann müsste man formulieren: "Der Minister sagte sinngemäß, dass man zeitnah zu einer Lösung kommen müsse."

Answer (score 1):

Die rechtliche Lage (amtliches Regelwerk) und die Meinungen sind ja jetzt dargelegt.

Deswegen komme ich zu dem Schluss, dass groß geschrieben werden muss. Wenn das amtliche Regelwerk diesem Sonderfall keine Bedeutung zumisst, dann ist die Botschaft eindeutig:

> Wenn keine Einschränkung greift, greift die allgemeine Regel.

Und die besagt, dass man den Anfang eines Ganzsatzes, also was zwischen zwei Punkten steht (und damit sind nicht die Punkte gemeint, die als Abkz. dienen – die sind nämlich keine syntaktischen Satzzeichen), groß schreibt.

In deinem Fall ist die Kleinschreibung ohnehin nicht dringlich. Die Empfehlung lautet – gestärkt vom Rückenwind der Regeln – Großschreibung. Denn ein klein geschriebener Satzanfang ist mehr als ungewöhnlich und führt im besten Falle dazu, dass man verdutzt aufschaut und die befremdliche Stelle im Textfluss für zwei Sekunden mustert.

Mich hat dieses Problem auch schon heimgesucht:

> ›pH-Wert‹ und ›i-Punkt‹ sind solche Problemwörter.

Was nun?

> ›PH-Wert‹ und ›i-Punkt‹ sind solche Problemwörter.

Das stößt höchstens den Chemikern bitter auf. Die ultimative Lösung liegt bei Orthograpieverständnisschwierigkeiten immer im kreativen Teil des Gehirns: Umformulieren! Statt sich im Gestrüpp zu verheddern, macht man es auf die elegante Weise und fährt Autobahn:

> Solche Problemwörter sind ›pH-Wert‹ und ›i-Punkt‹.

PS: Übrigens würde ich ›einfache Guillemets‹ oder *Kursivierung* für deinen Fall verwenden, da »doppelte Guillemets« oder "normale Computeranführungszeichen" wörtlichen Zitaten vorbehalten bleiben sollten.

Comment: Merkwürdig - einerseits hat die _Amtliche Rechtschreibregelung_ für Dich den Status einer Rechtsnorm (wer ahndet dann bitteschön wie Verstöße dagegen?), andererseits erklärst Du in Deinem PS ihren [Paragraphen 94](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf89-95.html) mal eben für irrelevant.

Comment: Die amtliche Rechtschreibung ist verbindlich für Schüler, Lehrer und Beamte. Das Regelwerk verliert kein Wort darüber, wann man welche Anführungszeichen oder Auszeichnungen wie verwenden soll. Mein PS ist die Vorgehensweise der Typographie.